# Is it better to pass by value or const ref when parameter is modified?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function where the logic requires me to modify the input parameter. I want it to leave the original variable unchanged, so will need to take a copy at some point.

Here is a simplified example. `X` is a type that is expensive to copy and I am choosing between `Bar1` and `Bar2`:

```
int Foo(const X&);

int Bar1(const X& x){
 // copy x to non-const local variable
 auto mutable_x {x};
 // call a non-const member function to change x, to make it give the desired result when passed to Foo
mutable_x.reverse();
return Foo(mutable_x);
}

int Bar2(X x){
x.reverse();
return Foo(x);
}
```

I feel like Bar2 is better because it will move-construct x when an rvalue is passed in, avoiding an unnecessary copy. Is this guaranteed?

The core guidelines do not seem to cover this case as far as I can tell (https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in). Maybe this means I should just take by const-reference as normal and accept the possibility of an extra copy.

Comment: "avoiding an unnecessary copy" you need a copy, so the copy is not unnecessary.

Comment: You need a copy. So you have to copy. I would do `Bar2` as it is cleaner and easier to read

Comment: What I meant was if you pass an rvalue into Bar1, it will materialise it and then copy it on the next line. If you pass it to Bar2, it will be move constructed and no copy will take place. There's an additional copy in Bar1 in this case so it felt unnecessary

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `Bar1` copies twice when given an rvalue

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, that's essentially what I wanted to check. Bar2 should be more efficient for rvalues.

Comment: `const X&` is a safe choice, but do not overthink this. This looks like micro-optimization. Is this code time critical? If yes then first write performance measurement test. Then try both approaches (result of performance test will let you to make choice). If it is not time critical code do not waste your time on unimportant detail. Please remember there is "As-if rule" which can allow optimizer to tweak  your code in both cases to same result.

Comment: well, does two constructions, a materialisation and a copy, instead of one materialisation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bar2` is superior, not just because it avoids an extra construction. `Bar1` has an extra object in scope, which could be confused for the working value.

```
int Bar1_BadRefactor(const X& x){
 // copy x to non-const local variable
 auto mutable_x {x};
 // call a non-const member function to change x, to make it give the desired result when passed to Foo
mutable_x.reverse();
 // some more code
 return Foo(x); // whoops
}
```

Comment: There are guidelines which enforce to not modify input parameters though...

Comment: Creating `reversed` function, and you might refactor as `return Foo(reversed(x));` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 do you mean things like "F.8: Prefer pure functions" and "Con.1: By default, make objects immutable"? Yes, in many ways it would be better to have `return Foo(reversed(x))`, where this doesn't matter, but sometimes you don't control `X`

Comment: I meant with proposed refacto, that OP's question is still valid: `return Foo(reversed(std::move(x)));`, whereas your (old) valid argument is no longer relevant. (I would also use `Bar2` BTW).

Answer (score 0):

See the note in [F.16](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f16-for-in-parameters-pass-cheaply-copied-types-by-value-and-others-by-reference-to-const) (emphasis mine):

> **For advanced uses (only)**, where you really need to optimize for rvalues passed to “input-only” parameters:
>
> - [...]
> - If the function is going to keep a copy of the argument, in addition to passing by `const&` (for lvalues), add an overload that passes the parameter by `&&` (for rvalues) and in the body `std::moves` it to its destination. Essentially this overloads a “will-move-from”; see F.18.

Essentially, they seem to suggest that it's premature optimisation to worry about it. If you do need that performance, make it into two overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I interpreted that more as the case where you want to store a copy of the parameter in a static/member variable for later use. It makes sense then that you'd use an overload, but I'm not sure it's the same as creating a copy for local use within the function